# How can put an id text in a text box by click on it?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I want that when I click on `id` it sends my value in `id=arxidia` and when I click again on mounoxilo it removes it.

```
<div class="poutsa" id="mounoxilo1" value="vizia1">etsi1</div>
<div class="poutsa" id="mounoxilo2" value="vizia2">etsi2</div>
<div class="poutsa" id="mounoxilo3" value="vizia3">etsi3</div>
<div class="poutsa" id="mounoxilo4" value="vizia4">etsi4</div>

<input type="text" id="arxidia">
```

Comment: Unsure what you are asking? What is mounoxilo and arxidia?

Comment: Show us what you have tried to do.

Comment: When click on id mounoxilo send the value to textbox

Comment: sst esu mipos kseris pos na to kanw?

Answer (score 0):

using jquery

```
jQuery("#mounoxilo").click(function(){
    if(jQuery("#arxidia").val() == "") {
        jQuery("#arxidia").val(jQuery("#mounoxilo").attr("value"));
    } else {
        jQuery("#arxidia").val("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not using jQuery:

```
document.getElementById('mounoxilo').onclick = function(e) {
    var inputEl = document.getElementById('arxidia');
    if(inputEl.value) {
        inputEl.value = "";
    } else {
        inputEl.value = this.getAttribute('value');
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XwAY5/

For the edited question it's like this:

```
var divEls = document.getElementsByClassName('poutsa');

for(var i = 0; i < divEls.length; i++) {

    divEl = divEls[i];

    divEl.onclick = function(e) {
        var inputEl = document.getElementById('arxidia');
        if(inputEl.value == this.getAttribute('value')) {
            inputEl.value = "";
        } else {
            inputEl.value = this.getAttribute('value');
        }
    }

}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XwAY5/2/

**EDIT 2**

Appearently, the input should be able to hold multiple values, so I came up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/XwAY5/3/

Comment: Ok this is the right answer! And if i whant use it not by mounoxilo but an id?

Comment: I have change my question if i have more id's how can make it to work?

Comment: I updated my answer so that it works for all elements with the class 'poutsa'

Comment: Very nice but the value disappear when i click on another value

Comment: I thought that was you intention. I updated the fiddle again (http://jsfiddle.net/XwAY5/3/), is this what you want?

Comment: And please one last little question can make an from value at value? i need 12 reputation to vote up your answer

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Try explaining it with an example: so what should show up in the inputbox?